# Java Jackson how to parse large REST API JSON?

Tags: java, rest, jackson, java-http-client

I'm trying to get info from https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest

```
 HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .GET()
                    .uri(URI.create("https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest"))
                    .build();
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(response.body());
            JsonNode data = json.get("data");
            List<Data> items = new ArrayList<>();
            data.forEach(item -> {
                Data d = new Data(
                        item.get("high").asInt(),
                        item.get("highTime").asInt(),
                        item.get("low").asInt(),
                        item.get("lowTime").asInt()
                );
                items.add(d);

            });
```

Problem is the object is the `itemID`. So if I want the item id 6. I can't do it since it's not an attribute of the object.

> "2":{"high":164,"highTime":1672078170,"low":160,"lowTime":1672078164} ``

"2" is the `itemID` and the object.

Below is when I loop through the arraylist and print it out

```
Data{high=157, highTime=1672071161, low=150, lowTime=1672071151}
Data{high=187987, highTime=1672071066, low=182005, lowTime=1672070881}
Data{high=189903, highTime=1672071052, low=186820, lowTime=1672070884}
Data{high=190000, highTime=1672070957, low=184882, lowTime=1672070984}
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase this sentence *"Problem is the object is the itemID. So if I want the item id 6. I can't do it since even the class name returns and I can only get index"*? There's no property `itemID` in your sample data.

Comment: In the Rest API. The itemID is the object.

```
"2":{"high":164,"highTime":1672078170,"low":160,"lowTime":1672078164}
```

2 is the object. So how would I be able to get it since it isn't a attribute?

Comment: It looks rather like a Map `"2":{ ... }` (or you have an JSON-object with a property `"2"`). And there's no `itemID` that you've mentioned twice.

Comment: Also, please, **don't** post clarifications in the comments, [**update**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74922799/edit) the question.

Comment: *"So how would I be able to get it since it isn't a attribute?"* - as I've said `"2":{ ... }` looks like a `Map<Integer,Data>`, can you share the rest JSON (for now it's unclear how to access it from the enclosing JSON-object) ?

Comment: https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest All the JSON is here

Comment: Ok, also, please, share `Data` class (only declaration and fields).

Comment: Data class contains int high, int highTime, int low, int lowTime. no args constructor, all args constructors, getter/setters, and toString

Comment: Sure, that's absolutely clear, but you can add this class (only declaration and fields), so that anyone can copy-past it, instead of typing it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON has the following structure:

```
{
   "data":{
      "2":{ ... },
      "6":{ ... },
      "8":{ ... },
      "10":{ ... },
      "12":{ ... }
      ...
   }
}
```

And property `"data"` is associated not with an object, or a `List<Data>`, but with a `Map<Integer,Data>` (or `Map<String,Data>`.

There are several ways how you can parse:

- You can define an object with a single property `Map<Integer,Data> data`.

```
public static class DataWrapper {
    private Map<Integer, Data1> data;
    
    // getters, setters
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
String json = """
            {
               "data":{ ... }
            }
            """;

ObjectMapper mapper12 = new ObjectMapper();
        
DataWrapper dataWrapper = mapper12.readValue(json12, DataWrapper.class);
Map<Integer, Data1> dataMap = dataWrapper.getData();
    
System.out.println("item 6: " + dataMap.get(6));
```

- Another approach would be to create a `JsonNode` by parsing the given JSON, access the node mapped to the property `"data"` and parse it as a `Map` using `ObjectReader` and its method [`ObjectReader.readValue()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html#readValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)). To generate `ObjectReader` we can make use of the method [`ObjectMapper.readerFor()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerFor(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference)) which expects a `TypeReference`.

That's how the second approach might be implemented:

```
String json = """
            {
               "data":{ ... }
            }
            """;
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(json);
        
ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<Map<Integer, Data>>() {});
Map<Integer, Data> itemsMap = reader.readValue(tree.get("data"));
    
System.out.println("item 6: " + itemsMap.get(6));
```

*Output:*

```
item 6: Data{high=195500, highTime=1672079035, low=182009, lowTime=1672078518}
```

Comment: The output is not what I need. For example, If I ONLY WANT object 2, 56, 113, and 125. How would you get the high, highTime, low, lowTime for those only

Comment: @rairai See the update, you can access the required object using a `Map`.

Comment: k thanks it works. I would word it better, but how would you have worded the question?

Comment: @rairai I've added an example for the first approach (it's shorter, but requires defining a separate class). *"how would you have worded the question?"* - when you were mentioning "id 6" and then providing the map entry with the key `2` it looked a bit misleading for me, maybe it was worth to emphasize that you need the individual items (for instance like you've said in the comment "If I only want object 2, 56, 113, and 125"). Never mind, the *key take away* is that JSON-structure in Java can be represented as `Map`.